# Сборка больших объектов в .NET сборщиком мусора

Tags: c#, .net, clr

В .NET есть такое понятие, как [большой объект](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) - это объект весящий более 85,000 байт.

С такими объектами несколько иначе работает сборщик мусора и всё такое.

Так вот, вопрос в том:

Что входит в эти 85,000? Сумма всех маленьких объектов внутри объекта (агрегация) или только сам объект (скажем, здоровенный массив INT'ов)? Мне кажется, что второй вариант. Однако, в MSDN что-то подтверждения не нашёл.

Answer (score 3):

- Если это массив примитивов, то нужно считать примитивы.
- Если это массив объектов, то не нужно считать все внутренности объекта, учитываются лишь сами ссылки (`4` или `8` в зависимости от архитектуры). Так что, если это массив объектов, то на x64 туда можно запихать `85000/8`.

Со списками, к слову, всё сложнее из-за capacity. Размер внутреннего массива куда больше, чем на данный момент фактических элементов в нём.

Ссылки по теме:

- [CLR Inside Out: Large Object Heap Uncovered](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/june/clr-inside-out-large-object-heap-uncovered).
- [The large object heap on Windows systems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap).
- [Large Object Heap Improvements in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5/).
- [Programming C# 8.0: Build Cloud, Web, and Desktop Applications](https://books.google.ru/books?id=w07ADwAAQBAJ&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=C%23+build+object+85000&source=bl&ots=T_Lpms15Pr&sig=ACfU3U0hzhjjuxkDzyM2af84GQR8qaAuHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9w9q1jPDmAhXxwsQBHRadAWMQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=C%23%20build%20object%2085000&f=false).

Comment: А заголовок объекта считается? У массива ещё вроде должна длина где-то храниться.

Comment: @Qwertiy из того, что я находил, заголовки и метаданные вообще не упоминались.

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще, C# не мой профиль. Лучше, чтоб кто-нить шарящий ответил. Там ещё это менялось в различных версиях .NET